# IE9 not supported by Google Map API warning message

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have an application that uses Google Map API. The application is running on the  IE v9 browser.
The IE v9 is recently no longer supported by the API. This has caused a warning message to be displayed on the browser every time I log in, saying:

> You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps
>   JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser

However, I am not keen on moving to a higher version browser as some functionalities are not supported in the higher version. Is there a way I can stop the browser from displaying this message from the back end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove this using css.

```
.infomsg {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Anyone has an example of how to use it in a context?

Answer (score 0):

If you have webpage with a line like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=apikey" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check to have `v=3` (api version to use) or try changing `v=3` to `v=3.27`.